# ASP MVC Library for comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any freeware library (controls) for ASP MVC implementing posting and displaying comments?

Comment: What kind of comments? Do you really need library? It is easy to do it yourself and makes no sense to create libraries. There are no standardized ways of adding comments:)

Comment: yeah right, everything is easy, so why some other libraries are implemented?

the point is that sometimes you know how to do it, but don't have time to do it ...
thnx for voting down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not asp.net mvc specific, but You could try to integrate your app with [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

Getting quite popular lately.